# Shortcodes show up as text on page

Tags: wordpress, text, shortcode

For some reason, some of the shortcodes of some of my plugins show up as text on my pages. Could somebody please provide me with possible reasons why this is happening. The main plugins which are causing problems are:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-ultra/

wordpress.org/support/plugin/front-end-pm

I have also used the plugins individually, deactivated all of my other plugins one by one and they still show up as text. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding the shortcode on a page e.g. about us or through php?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your hwlp and apologies for the late reply. I'm adding the shortcodes to pages on my website. The instructions for one of the particular plugins are seen here:https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-pm/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

> `do_shortcode('[shortcode]');`

Put this in your theme file where you want the widget/what ever it is you want to do to appear.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply. I've placed this in the Page template(page.php) file but with no success.

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY certain that you're using complete PHP tags, e.g. `<?php ?>` but not `<? ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the two plugins in wordpress 4.0 and it works fine.

Did you try to update your wordpress version?

If the problem persists, try to switch to the Twenty Eleven theme to see if it's not a theme-specific problems

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and apologies for the late reply. I've updated to 4.0 due to your answer but this has led to an error on my page stating that I do not have the permission to view drafts. I have also tried the plugins in the twenty eleven theme on WordPress 3.9 but I recieve the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are editing in the text tab, and not HTML.

You can go to the HTML Tab and see if its wrapping your shortcodes in

tags, as this has caused problems for me in the past.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply. I've checked this in the text tab and it there are no other letters other than the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the shortcode from the "Visual/HTML" tab and pasted in "Text" section then updated Post.

Answer (score 0):

@Kristofer is correct if you're looking for a template-based solution, except it needs to be

```
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
```

not just

```
do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
```

Answer (score 0):

It will just display as text if the shortcode is not correct.  For example, in the Tag Groups plugin, the premium shortcodes will not display anything.